# Modal logic: justification of the rule of necessitation

Tags: logic

I'm studying some lecture notes about modal logic and I'm now reading a paragraph which goes as follows:

The rules of inference of system K are modus ponens and the rule of necessitation:

NEC: if A is a theorem, then ◻A is a theorem.

This rule is legitimate in that it preserves truth in a world in any model: if A is true in a world w, it must be true in every world accessible from w, so ◻A is true in w.

I don't quite understand the last line ("This rule is legitimate..."). Do you have any guesses? Maybe the correct phrasing should have been: if A is true in a world w and it is a theorem...

Comment: Note that we are speaking of logical theorems... The intuitive concept of logical truth is exactly "true in every possible world" (see [Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/leibniz/#SomFunPriLei)).

Comment: Yes, but I still can't understand that line.

Comment: Maybe the "intended reading" is : the rule licenses to infer from the truth in a world in a model to the truth in every ...". It works like Generalization rule: if we can prove $\varphi(x)$ with $x$ whatever, we are legitimate (by the rule) to assert $\forall x \varphi(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a very good explanation -- arguably even wrong. I would instead say something like

> If $A$ is a *theorem*, then it had better be true in *every* possible world. In particular, if $w$ is some world, then $A$ is true in every world accessible from $w$, so $\Box A$ is true in $w$. But $w$ was arbitrary, so $\Box A$ is *itself* true in every world. So it is legitimate to declare that $\Box A$ should be a theorem.

If $A$ is not actually a theorem, it may still *incidentally* be true in some world, and then $\Box A$ doesn't have to be true in that world.

Answer (score 0):

You write "This rule is legitimate in that it preserves truth in a world in any model".

This is not true. Necessitation preserves truth in a model but not truth in a world in a model. It is easy to see that what is true in a world need not be necessarily so in that world, hence adding the box operator may not preserve truth.